# Get index of string in an array of NSAttributedString in swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsattributedstring

I have an array of NSattributedstring. I want to get the index of a string in the array. I am using the following code.

```
let textToSearch = "My name is Amrit"
let index = find(myArray, textToSearch)
```

myArray is an array of NsattributedString. As both the types of array and textTosearch are different.

```
 indexArray = ["1. THE OPENING","2. THE COW","3. THE FAMILY OF  IMRAN","4. WOMEN","5. THE FEAST","6. LIVESTOCK","7. THE HEIGHTS","8. BATTLE GAINS","9. REPENTANCE","10. JONAH","11. HUD","12. JOSEPH","13. THUNDER","14. ABRAHAM","15. AL-HIJR","16. THE BEE","17. THE NIGHT JOURNEY","18. THE CAVE","19. MARY","20. TA HA","21. THE PROPHETS","22. THE PILGRIMAGE","23. THE BELIEVERS","24. LIGHT","25. THE DIFFERENTIATOR","26. THE POETS","27. THE ANTS","28. THE STORY","29. THE SPIDER","30. THE BYZANTINES","31. LUQMAN","32. BOWING DOWN IN WORSHIP","33. THE JOINT FORCES","34. SHEBA","35. THE CREATOR","36. YA SIN","37. RANGED IN ROWS","38. SAD","39. THE THRONGS","40. THE FORGIVER","41. [VERSES] MADE DISTINCT","42. CONSULTATION","43. ORNAMENTS OF GOLD","44. SMOKE","45. KNEELING","46. THE SAND DUNES","47. MUHAMMAD","48. TRIUMPH","49. THE PRIVATE ROOMS","50. QAF","51. SCATTERING [WINDS]","52. THE MOUNTAIN","53. THE STAR","54. THE MOON","55. THE LORD OF MERCY","56. THAT WHICH IS COMING","57. IRON","58. THE DISPUTE","59. THE GATHERING [OF FORCES]","60. WOMEN TESTED","61. SOLID LINES","62. THE DAY OF CONGREGATION","63. THE HYPOCRITES","64. MUTUAL NEGLECT","65. DIVORCE","66. PROHIBITION","67. CONTROL","68. THE PEN","69. THE INEVITABLE HOUR","70. THE WAYS OF ASCENT","71. NOAH","72. THE JINN","73. ENFOLDED","74. WRAPPED IN HIS CLOAK","75. THE RESURRECTION","76. MAN","77. [WINDS] SENT FORTH","78. THEANNOUNCEMENT","79. THE FORCEFUL CHARGERS","80. HE FROWNED","81. SHROUDED IN DARKNESS","82. TORN APART","83. THOSE WHO GIVE SHORT MEASURE","84. RIPPED APART","85. THE TOWERING CONSTELLATIONS","86. THE NIGHT-COMER","87. THE MOST HIGH","88. THE OVERWHELMING EVENT","89. DAYBREAK","90. THE CITY","91. THE SUN","92. THE NIGHT","93. THE MORNING BRIGHTNESS","94. RELIEF","95. THE FIG","96. THE CLINGING FORM","97. THE NIGHT OF GLORY","98. CLEAR EVIDENCE","99. THE EARTHQUAKE","100. THE CHARGING STEEDS","101. THE CRASHING BLOW","102. STRIVING FOR MORE","103. THE DECLINING DAY","104. THE BACKBITER","105. THE ELEPHANT","106. QURAYSH","107. COMMON KINDNESSES","108. ABUNDANCE","109. THE DISBELIEVERS","110. HELP","111. PALM FIBRE","112. PURITY [OF FAITH]","113. DAYBREAK","114. PEOPLE"]

 if let rtfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("quaran3", withExtension: "rtf") {
            let attributedStringWithRtf = NSMutableAttributedString(fileURL: rtfPath, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!

            var lengthOfRtf = attributedStringWithRtf.length
            divideFactor = Int(lengthOfRtf/endIndex)
            println(divideFactor)

            self.updateTextFont(attributedStringWithRtf) (valueFactor: divideFactor) (totalRange: lengthOfRtf)
            self.getTheIndexNumber(attributedStringWithRtf) (valueFactor: divideFactor)


        }


func updateTextFont(mystring:NSMutableAttributedString) (valueFactor:Int) (totalRange : Int) {

    let screenSizeMain: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let myAttriText:NSMutableAttributedString = mystring.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    myAttriText.beginEditing()
    myAttriText.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, myAttriText.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions.Reverse) { (attribute, range, stop) -> Void in
        var mutableAttributes = NSDictionary(dictionary: attribute)
        var font:UIFont = mutableAttributes.objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as! UIFont
        var newFont:UIFont = font.fontWithSize(font.pointSize)

        if DeviceType.IS_IPAD
        {
            newFont = font.fontWithSize(font.pointSize+7)

        }
        var fontProperties:UIFontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor()
        let sizeNumber:Float = fontProperties.fontAttributes()[UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute] as! Float
        myAttriText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range)

    }

    for var i=0; i <= valueFactor; i++ {
      //  if valueFactor*
        if startIndex == 885819 {


        }


        //let checkCurrentRange = valueFactor*endIndex
        let exactEndIndex : Int = endIndex
        if (totalRange - startIndex) < endIndex
        {
            endIndex = totalRange - startIndex
                let rangeFinal =  NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)
                var nsTextFinal = myAttriText.attributedSubstringFromRange(rangeFinal)
                pageText.append(nsTextFinal)
            endIndex = exactEndIndex

            return
        }



        let range =  NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)

        var nsText = myAttriText.attributedSubstringFromRange(range)

        for index in endIndex..<endIndex+100
        {
            let rangeNew =  NSMakeRange(endIndex + startIndex-1,1)
            var checkSpace = myAttriText.attributedSubstringFromRange(rangeNew)
            let stirngNew = checkSpace.string
            if stirngNew == " "
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                endIndex++
            }


        }
          let rangeFinal =  NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)

        var nsTextFinal = myAttriText.attributedSubstringFromRange(rangeFinal)

        pageText.append(nsTextFinal)
        println(startIndex)
        startIndex = startIndex + endIndex
        endIndex = exactEndIndex

    }

    myAttriText.endEditing()

}

func visibleRangeOfTextView(textView: NSAttributedString) -> NSRange {
    return NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)

}

func getTheIndexNumber(attribSring:NSMutableAttributedString) (valueFactor:Int) //-> NSMutableArray
{


    for index in 0..<indexArray.count {

        let text = indexArray.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString
        var lengthOfRtf = attribSring.length
        var textNew = attribSring.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, lengthOfRtf))
        var stirngNew : NSMutableString = attribSring.mutableString.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString
      //  println(stirngNew)
        var range: NSRange = (stirngNew as NSString).rangeOfString(text as String)
        var checkSpace = attribSring.attributedSubstringFromRange(range)
        let stirngNewCheck = checkSpace.string

        let pageIndex = (range.location / endIndex)
        indeArryInt.addObject(pageIndex)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let index = myArray.indexOf { $0.string == textToSearch }
```

This returns an `Int?`, the first index where a match is found. If there's no match, it will return `nil`.

Comment: I tried but it says [NsAttributedString doesnot have a member named indexOf]

Comment: Is `myArray` an **array** of `NSAttributedString`, or just an `NSAttributedString`? Show me the definition of `myArray`.

Comment: Its an array of NSAttributedString. I am making that array from a RTF file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift 1.2 you will need to map array of NSAttributedString to String array so find function can be called with correct values

```
let index = find(myArray.map({ attributedString in
    return attributedString.string
}), textToSearch)
```

@ZoffDino answer would work like a charm in Swift 2.0

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. But it always returns nil. I am not getting any match. Though there are a number of matches

Comment: @user3730935 Can you please post your code how do you declare your NSAttributedString array and how do you place elements on it?

Comment: I have updated my code above in the post. In the function getTheIndexNumber() I am creating an array for the indexes of occurance of string in the Rtf. This is an alternative way I am using for getting the index.

But getting the index from the array will be easier and exact. The above method I am using is creating a difference of 1 index.